# Access problems closing form with incomplete record

Tags: forms, ms-access, error-handling

I am trying to create a form in datasheet view, with certain fields pre-populated.

If a user clicks the X to close the form while a record is incomplete, I cannot find a way to gracefully give them the option of returning to the dirty record to correct it.

BeforeUpdate runs but setting Cancel=True doesn't stop the form closing.

Form_Unload runs and setting Cancel=True prevents close, but wipes the form contents (I haven't checked, but it appears to apply an Undo).

If I had control over when the X to close the form was enabled I might be able to avoid this.  But I don't, and since I'm in datasheet view, I can't offer a close button.

The problem is that while I can use BeforeUpdate to tell the user there is a problem and I am returning them to the form to correct it, I am made a liar if the trigger action is form close (rather than record save/navigation).  So the next message they receive is oops, we're closing you without saving, bad luck (your fault but too late now)!

Not to mention that despite cancelling update, the user receives a "You can't save this record at this time" message before the Form_Unload begins.

Any suggestions?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

you have to play around with several events for this. at the top of the code add a variable to track form errors:

```
Dim frmErr As Boolean
```

when the form loads, and when there's an entry-error, set the error to true

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    frmErr = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    frmErr = True
End Sub
```

when the user tries to close the form:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    If Not Me.Dirty Then 'user hasn't done anything.
        If MsgBox("form is unchanged. close?", vbYesNoCancel, "really?") = vbYes Then
            frmErr = False
        End If
    End If

    If frmErr = True Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

this is a basic outline. you might have to play around with the Form_Dirty event as well as before update to make it work the way you need.

Comment: The problem is when I trap the error of an incompletely filled out record on form unload, the form contents are erased rather than leaving them partially filled out, so the user can complete them properly. @wazz